# Accessibility issues coming in MUI components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accessibility, wave, wcag

I am developing a react application using MUI (Core & X) & having issues in WCAG Accessibility.
I am using many of their components but having issues in data grid, select and MUI tabs.
I am using the following MUI versions:

"@mui/material": "^5.13.5",
"@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.8.0",
"@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.8",

**Issues found are:**

- Wave Evaluation Tool (i.e Accessibility test) is giving Form Label Missing Error wherever there's a dropdown arrow either in MUI Data Grid(after rows per page)
- Also in any of MUI Select Component (dropdown for selection) . https://justpaste.it/4q585  [[Data Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GzNy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U3Cv.png)
- as well as Broken-Aria Reference error in MUI Tabs[Broken-Aria Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0XC9.png)

Is this a limitation in MUI or am I doing some thing wrong. Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Huzaifa

Comment: Since you aren't including your code, we have no way to tell whether or not you are doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your first two errors are the same.  The table pagination uses a MUI Select Component and it's causing the error in both scenarios.  I used a MUI Data Grid demo page to test the grid.

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/pagination/

The coding for the MUI Select is very non-standard:

```
<input aria-invalid="false" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" 
  class="MuiSelect-nativeInput css-1k3x8v3" value="5">
```

It has `aria-hidden="true"` so the <input> will be hidden from screen readers (and other assistive technology) and it has `tabindex="-1"`, which prevents a keyboard user from <kbd>tabbing</kbd> to it. So there's no way for a user to get their focus (keyboard or assistive tech) on the <input>. The non-standard coding is fooling the [WebAIM WAVE tool](https://wave.webaim.org/). You can ignore the error.

The MUI Select should have `display:none` on that <input> rather than `aria-hidden` and `tabindex`. That would prevent the WAVE error and the example still works as expected. You should file a bug with MUI.

Your third error with MUI Tabs, I could not replicate with https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/.  The basic construct of the tabs is:

```
<div aria-label="basic tabs example" role="tablist">
  <button role="tab" aria-selected="true"  id="simple-tab-0">Item One</button>
  <button role="tab" aria-selected="false" id="simple-tab-1">Item Two</button>
  <button role="tab" aria-selected="false" id="simple-tab-2">Item Three</button>
</div>
...
<div role="tabpanel" id="simple-tabpanel-0" aria-labelledby="simple-tab-0"></div>
<div role="tabpanel" id="simple-tabpanel-1" aria-labelledby="simple-tab-1" hidden=""></div>
<div role="tabpanel" id="simple-tabpanel-2" aria-labelledby="simple-tab-2" hidden=""></div>
```

Notice that each <button> has an ID ("simple-tab-0", 1, 2) and then later each `<div role="tabpanel">` has `aria-labelledby` pointing to one of the button IDs.  That's perfectly valid (which is why the demo page doesn't have any WAVE errors).

The screenshot you posted shows the third <div> with `aria-labelledby="simple-tab-2"` is being flagged in error. If that happens, that means the <button> with `id="simple-tab-2"` is missing.